# MVC4Demo.Models.Employee: : EntityType 'Employee' has no key defined

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

When I run Employee detail view then the following error is displayed. There are no issues related to database connectivity.

> List itemDefine the key for this EntityType.  Employees: EntityType: EntitySet 'Employees' is based on type 'Employee' that has no keys defined.

Comment: please add some code. The employee class, the code where the error occurs etc etc ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [EntityType 'ApplicantPosition' has no key defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764609/entitytype-applicantposition-has-no-key-defined)

Answer (score 1):

Code First would infer that a property is a primary key if the property is called `Id` or `<class name>Id.`

So, just add a such property to your model or you can also use `[Key]` attribute to map it a primary key.

For example:

```
public class Employee
{
   [Key]
   public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
   //Other properties
}
```

Comment: thanks for your above replay because it has solved my previous error but now i got new error given below.[Cannot open database "MVC4Demo" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool'.] so, how can i resolve this error.

Comment: @user2899935 If my answer solved your problem, please accept it as the question is answered here. You might have deleted the database or you must have put wrong connection string. Consider putting a different question for new problem, probably with more information.