# Error during running MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Please tell me the meaning of this error?

> {"One or more validation errors were detected during model
>   generation:\r\n\r\nMvcDemo.Models.Employee: : EntityType 'Employee'
>   has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.\r\nemp:
>   EntityType: EntitySet 'emp' is based on type 'Employee' that has no
>   keys defined.\r\n"}

Comment: What platform/language/whatever is this about? asp.net-mvc?

Comment: Sir ii m using C# .net MVC.

Comment: possible duplicate of [EntityType 'ApplicantPosition' has no key defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764609/entitytype-applicantposition-has-no-key-defined)

Comment: You'd better to post the code block that causes this error.